# Ошибка в Forge (создание модов)

Tags: java, aforge

Меня направили сюда из другого форума. Суть в том, что выдаёт ошибку что он не распознал переменную JAVA_HOME, а точнее её путь (наверно). Короче, всё на скриншоте[image: Ошибка] версия для разработки 1.7.10

Comment: Кажется тебе может помочь изменение переменной среды JAVA_HOME на корректное значение, можешь погуглить "изменить JAVA_HOME" или подождать пока кто-нибудь добрый напишет подробную инструкцию

Answer (score 1):

Вы говорите что используете версию

> версия для разработки 1.7.10

а переменная окружения ссылается на версию 1.8.0_131 (скачана ли она у вас)?

В любом случае проверьте настройку переменной окружения

```
Windows

Windows 10 и Windows 8
В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.
Windows 7
На рабочем столе правой кнопкой нажмите на значок Компьютер.
В контекстном меню выберите Свойства.
Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.
Windows XP
Нажмите Пуск, выберите Панель управления, дважды нажмите на Система и выберите вкладку Дополнительно.
Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.
```

> Оригинал https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Скорее всего 1.7.10 это версия minecraft :)